# Order json array by Name ASC dont works on Chrome

Tags: php, jquery, json

Hi guys i have this code

```
$Sql = "SELECT * FROM tabmakes
    WHERE Type_Id = '1'
    ORDER BY Make_Name Asc";
$Query = mysql_query($Sql,$Conn) or die(mysql_error($Conn));
$marcas = array();
  while ($Rs = mysql_fetch_array($Query)) {
    $marcas[ $Rs['Marca_Id'] ] = $Rs['Marca_Nome'];
    }
     asort($marcas); // tried using asort only works on firefox     
     echo ( json_encode($marcas) );
```

and this is my jquery

```
$("#div-test-1").change(function(){
    var tmpTipo = $(".buscaMarcas").val();
    $.getJSON("/php/getMakes.php",{tipo: tmpTipo, marca: $(this).val()}, function(resposta){
        if(resposta === null){
            var options = '<option value="">-</option>';
        }
        else{
            var options = '<option value="">-</option>';
            $.each(resposta, function(key, val) {
                options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + val + '</option>';
            });
        }
        $("select.recebeModelos").html(options);
        $("select.recebeEstilos").html('<option value="">-</option>');
    });
});
```

The json output came ordered by NAME but the Select when get populated it all information, the values come ordered by ID.

So how i can get the result and show on select ordered by NAME.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're building an array in PHP. Even though you're building it in NAME order based on what's coming out of PHP, when PHP starts the json conversion process, it's going to build it in numerical key order. You then also enforce that numerical key order by running the array through `asort()`.

One way around it is to change how the array's built:

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $data[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'name' => $row['name'])
}
```

Of course, this'll require changes in the JS code to handle the new structure, but this will preserve the name ordering.

Comment: I dont understand why on firefox works fine, but on chrome not.. i will continuous look for a away if possible to fix this without change the php codes, becuz i have alot of codes like this for makes, models, details etc - so i will keep looking for a away to do something on the jquery maybe.. thanks

Comment: @Alvaro, you probably have some other javascript or browser addon causing it. It would be very wrong for chrome to decide to modify html on its own unprovoked.

Comment: i will remove all javascript not necessary and also try this with last jquery version and just the function need on a new fresh installation becuz this let me crazy, works fine on firefox and chrome not.. thanks.